# Username validation in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to validate username using python regex.
Requirements for username:

1. Total length of the username should be 6
2. It should have 1 Capital letter, 1 special character, and 4 small letters
3. Not more than 1 special char and  1 capital letter allowed
4. positions are not defined. I mean either it can start from small letter, or a big letter or with special char.

Please help me in writing regex for this.

I want to achieve this only one line.

Thanks,
Sujatha

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Ken,  I tried resolving this. [a-zA-Z$@-]{6} will fulfill part of username requirement. But its not completely right. This validation is done in multiple lines. I am trying to find out if we can do it in one line regex. Please help me

Comment: What about `^(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){4})(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^$@-]*[$@-])[a-zA-Z$@-]{6,}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex**: [`^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){4})(?=.*[$@_])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z$@_]{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/VPc4YW/4)

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of the string
- `(?=)` Positive Lookahead

  - `(?:.*[a-z]){4}` Matches any character between zero and unlimited times
    followed by lowercase letter `a-z` exactly `4` times
  - `.*[@]` Matches any character between zero and unlimited times
    followed by special chars `$@_`
  - `.*[A-Z]` Matches any character between zero and unlimited times
    followed by capital letter `A-Z`
- `[a-zA-Z$@_]{6}` Match a single character present in the list `6` times
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the string

Comment: sujat@ this is a valid username in my case. But not matching. Username length should be exactly 6. From given regex, .*[@] Matches any character between zero and unlimited times followed by special chars @.

Comment: @sujatharathod My regex dose exactly what you asked and you can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/VPc4YW/2

Comment: @sujatharathod Where is your capital letter in your example `sujat@`?

Comment: My bad. Yes it matches. Thank you very much

Comment: @sujatharathod How many special characters you have?

Comment: only $, @ and _ should be allowed in this case.

Comment: @sujatharathod You can use @ctwheels regex its far more efficient then mine, just remove `,` in `{6,}`.

Comment: Thanks. Will go through more about regex. The expression is advanced. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Will refer @ctwheels and see how to build efficient expression.